# matlab loop through nxn matrix getting stuck in infinite loop

Tags: matlab

I have 2 nxn matrices in matlab, I want to check all elements of m1 and if the value of m1(x,y) is <100 or >200 set the value of m2(x,y) to be 1. 
This should be super simple, but its being written in matlab, and it endlessly loops for some reason that I don't understand. 
Here is the code

```
for q=1:256
    for w=1:256
         if m1(q,w) > 200 | m1(q,w) < 100
                m2(q,w) = 1
         end
    end
end
```

Comment: Why do you say this is an endless loop? Maybe it’s slow because you didn’t pre-allocate `m2`? Add `m2=zeros(size(m1))` before the loop.  In any case, you don’t need a loop here, the code will be faster and more readable without the loop: `m2=m1>200|m1<100`.

Comment: As a general comment - Nested looping in matlab is often a sign that there is a better way you can do it.  Matlab is interpreted so lots of instruction execution can be slow, however it is really good at doing things in parallel.  See [the matlab vectorization documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) for more info.

Comment: And before anybody else comments I know that [modern matlab is not as slow as it used to be](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/), however it is still better practice (more readable, less error prone, what it is designed for) to use vectorization.

Answer (score 5):

Your original code is ok, but it takes a long time to display the output.

Note that when the line that assigns a value to m2 as below:

```
m2(q,w) = 1
```

Matlab displays the entire m2 matrix, for each iteration of the for loops, which takes significant time to do line by line.

To fix, add a semicolon to prevent displaying the m2 matrix, and you should see execution times as below:

```
tic
m1 = round(255*rand(256));
for q=1:256
    for w=1:256
         if m1(q,w) > 200 | m1(q,w) < 100
                m2(q,w) = 1;
         end
    end
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.011460 seconds.
```

Lastly, Cris Luengo in the comments section has an elegant way of performing your calculation as well.